# Dynamically import a TypeScript type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, import, dynamic-import

there are a lot of questions about TypeScript dynamic import, however they seem to be systematically focused on dynamically import a JavaScript object.

I'd like to be able to import a type dynamically too. Say for example that I want to import the `Feature` type from `leaflet`.

Importing `leaflet` is not allowed in the context of server-side rendering. Importing `@types/leaflet` isn't allowed either, it's considered an error by TypeScript.

So currently I must manually copy the typings in my app, and import them.

Note that I am using Next.js `dynamic` imports but it does not change the issue as far as I know. Related issue: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/11196

Any idea how to import a TypeScript type more cleanly, without actually importing the underlying JS lib, in the context of dynamic imports?

Comment: I haven't fully understood your case, but maybe [import types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types) are a thing here? You can import the types like `import("leaflet").Mytype` without having an actual ES module import.

Comment: Yeah [`import type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#-type-only-imports-and-export)  syntax as described in the link seems to match my need. Will try that tomorrow.